# pass list from listbox to mvc controller with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor

I would like to know how I can pass a list with values in MVC method via jquery. I have a jquery UI dialog in which records are pasted in each row. Once the user will click the submit button, I want to have a jquery which will post the values from the popup multiline textbox to the method.
Is that possible?
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: you can easily pass the list values to the action as an array of strings.

Comment: @CoffeeCode can you please give me an example how I can do that with Jquery. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done simply get the values from the list and pass the to the controller.

your java script will look something like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
        //parsing and collecting the values from the list
        var values = { 'values': 'your string array here'};

         $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: "/controller/YourAction",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        data: values
    });
    });
```

and you will have such an action in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult YourAction(string[] values)
    {
        //your action here
        return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: why jquery for this task? The listbox should be bound to a ListViewModel having a SelectedIds Array. if you click the button just add an int selectedIds parameter in the action and the modelbinder will return the selected ids!